# Intent.putExtra (key,value) is not working

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-bundle

I got a `ValueEventListener`

```
   query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(BackgroundService.this, NextActivity.class);
                Task<String> t=genrate();//not null

                        t.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                 intent.putExtra("token",task.getResult());

            }
        } });
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(BackgroundService.this, 0, intent, 0);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setVisibility(VISIBILITY_SECRET);
                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(BackgroundService.this);
                notificationManager.notify(121, mBuilder.build());

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The `token` key is missing from `NextActivity`.

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("token")
```

return `null`.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: you do not seem to be using this Intent anywhere

Comment: In this line: `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(BackgroundService.this, 0, intent, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addValueEventListener()` is asynchronous. You will get the result only inside `onDataChange()`. Move the code to show notification into a separate method and call it inside `onDataChange()`.

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(BackgroundService.this, NextActivity.class);
                Task < String > t = genrate(); //not null

                t.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < String > () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < String > task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            intent.putExtra("token", task.getResult());

                            //Show notification here
                            showNotification(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
});
```

Separate method to show notification.

```
private void showNotification(Intent intent) {
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(BackgroundService.this, 0, intent, 0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setVisibility(VISIBILITY_SECRET);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(BackgroundService.this);
    notificationManager.notify(121, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this flag:  `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in your `PendingIntent`

Change:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(BackgroundService.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

to:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(BackgroundService.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: yeah , i checked with logs all is fine , btw  token is a long string

Comment: How long? and what is `task.getResult()`?

Comment: @somebody so without the flag would you get the extra?

Comment: yes , for debugging reasons i used the flag to update the pending intent

Answer (score 0):

Does your `task.getResult()` returns string? If yes, then try this in second activity.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String result = extras.getString("token");                
    System.out.println("yeah"+result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you are not calling `startActivity(intent);`

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(BackgroundService.this, NextActivity.class);
                Task < String > t = genrate(); //not null

                t.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < String > () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < String > task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            intent.putExtra("token", task.getResult());
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(BackgroundService.this, 0, intent, 0);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setVisibility(VISIBILITY_SECRET);
                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(BackgroundService.this);
                notificationManager.notify(121, mBuilder.build());

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```